# hide my application in intent chooser dialog when click on gmail notification in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, intentfilter, android-intent-chooser

I want to see my application in Chooser dialog when I click any type of file or click on **gmail attachment** or **share** any file in my android device. So to achieve this functionality I used below intent filters.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.ShareWithAttachmentActivity"
            android:label="Adoddle"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <!---->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!--<data android:mimeType="*/*" />-->
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/javascript" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/richtext" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/uri-list" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/xml" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/css  " />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But when I click on **gmail notification** App chooser Dialog opens and in that chooser I can see my application. And when I click on my application it gets crashed. As per my requirement my app shouldn't be displayed in that app chooser dialog when I click on that **gmail notification**.

I refered below links for that but didn't help me.

1. [Android: Registering Intent Filter to open email attachment with my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462816/android-registering-intent-filter-to-open-email-attachment-with-my-app)
2. [Android - Opening gmail attachment with my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431479/android-opening-gmail-attachment-with-my-app)
3. [Intent filter to download attachment from gmail apps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android)

Comment: Could you please clarify how to trigger the gmail notification app chooser dialog ?

Comment: give `<data android:mimeType="application/*" />` to trigger the gmail notification app chooser dialog

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this. When you click on gmail notification then it's mime type is `"application/gmail-ls"`. So exclude this mime type in your application. So remove `<data android:mimeType="application/*" />` and specify whatever type you want to filter. (e.g. **application/zip** ,**application/msword** etc. )

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.ShareWithAttachmentActivity"
            android:label="Adoddle"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <!---->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/zip"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/msword"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="application/pdf"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="audio/*"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="image/*"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="message/*"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="multipart/*"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/plain"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/html"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/javascript"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/richtext"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/uri-list"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/xml"
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="text/css  "
                    android:scheme="content" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:mimeType="video/*"
                    android:scheme="content" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove these two actions from `<intent-filter>`

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
```

Comment: Question Edited. I also want to see my app when share any file. SO I can't remove this actions.

Comment: Even for sharing you don't need to add these actions know. If you are sharing a file then you will open corresponding implicit intent which will handle this type of file.